# oval shape with background image

Tags: css

I am struggling with creating a CSS top right & conrner of the oval shap css. it should look like attached images.
[image]

```
  <style>
.up-next-container {
  width: 824px;
  height: 161px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.up-next-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

```
<div class="up-next-container">
                 <div class="up-next-inner">Hello</div>
             </div>
```

Comment: You should specify what is the problem and post at least some of your code, otherwise we won't be able to get 100% effective answers

Comment: something like this ? https://codepen.io/yasirhaleem/pen/ExjvBrw

Comment: @Yasir Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property for this:

```
clip-path: ellipse(50% 100% at 50% 100%);
```

This will clip your container with an ellipse with following properties:

- 50% radius on the x (effectively making the ellipse as wide as the container)
- 100%: radius on the y (making the ellipse twice the height of the container)
- 50%: x at the center of the container (nicely in the middle)
- 100%: y at the bottom of the container (this will cut off the lower half of the ellipse as it is outside of the container)